# Running a build script after calling vcvarsall.bat from powershell

Tags: c, visual-studio, powershell, cmd, build

I am attempting to run the Visual Studio (developer cmd prompt) environmental variable setup batch file followed by a build script from within a Powershell script as follows:

`cmd /v:on/k "(""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64_x86 && C:\buildscript.cmd --build-options)"`

It appears however that the environmental settings established by vcvarsall.bat are not retained for the build script call. i.e. no default compiler setup, etc.

Is the `/v:on` combined with the `/k` switch not actually utilizing the same cmd session and properly delaying environmental variable expansion? Perhaps the approach is wrong ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that when you run `cmd.exe` to run a batch file, the variables are set in that instance of `cmd.exe`, but they disappear after that instance terminates.

To work around this problem, you can use the Invoke-CmdScript function in this article:

[Windows IT Pro: Take Charge of Environment Variables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/take-charge-environment-variables-powershell)

The function is as follows:

```
# Invokes a Cmd.exe shell script and updates the environment.
function Invoke-CmdScript {
  param(
    [String] $scriptName
  )
  $cmdLine = """$scriptName"" $args & set"
  & $Env:SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe /c $cmdLine |
  select-string '^([^=]*)=(.*)$' | foreach-object {
    $varName = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
    $varValue = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
    set-item Env:$varName $varValue
  }
}
```

You could add this function to your PowerShell profile or use it as a script file.

Once you have defined the function, you can run your commands:

```
Invoke-CmdScript "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64_x86
C:\buildscript.cmd --build-options
```

...or whatever you need.

The article also presents a couple of functions that let you easily save and restore environment variables.

Comment: Shouldn't the `/K` switch retain the environment for execution of the subsequent command after the `&&` - since both are being called within the same `cmd` session?

Comment: I prefer to address the actual problem - export the environment variables from an executed `cmd.exe` batch file - rather than deal with the arcane idiosyncrasies of the `cmd.exe` command syntax.

Comment: Fair enough.  Accepting this as the solution - hopefully someone with some arcane CMD knowledge will pop-up with the solution.

Comment: I would add that exporting the variables to PowerShell means you can run other build steps without getting too "hacky." You can also use the `Get-Environment` function before running `Invoke-CmdScript`, and then use `Restore-Environment` function to clean up variables afterward.