# How do I integrate x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019 in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, cmd

I am trying to make "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019" as an integrated console for Visual Studio Code. [There was a solution for doing so with Developer Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68635853/how-do-i-get-visual-studio-developer-powershell-working-in-visual-studio-codes), but I have not seen one for what I'm trying to attempt. I know that "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019" is a shortcut to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat`

, but running it includes a few forms I'm not familiar with. For example, running `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat` directly I imagine does the proper setup to enable me to compile for a 64-bit target, but the console does not stick around afterwards (it closes subsequently). The shortcut works for some reason by having `%comspec% /k` prepended to the path as its target. So, running

`%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"`

with Run (win+r) gives me what I need. How do I replicate this in VS Code in `settings.json` just like with any other terminal/console profile? I've attempted the following, which I've taken from [How to make visual studio code run vcvarsx86_arm64.bat instead of vcvarsall.bat directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59012499/how-to-make-visual-studio-code-run-vcvarsx86-arm64-bat-instead-of-vcvarsall-bat):

```json
"x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019": {
    "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
    ],
    "args": [
        "/d",
        "/c",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat",
        "&"
    ],
    "icon": "terminal-cmd"
},
```

Comment: what happens when you run this terminal config? (is there an error message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is the config which worked for me:

```
"DevCmd": {
    "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
    ],
    "args": [
        "/d",
        "/k", 
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvarsall.bat",
        "amd64"]
}
```

In your example the argument `/c` means *'carry out the command and return'*, which in this scenario has the effect of'exit the shell'.

- `/k` means *'carry out the command and remain in the shell'*.
- `/d` means _'don't run the Auto commands for CMD in the registry.
- `&` is the [call operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) and is not needed. It's typically for chaining commands together on single line.

To get a complete list and explanation of available arguments run this in a Command Prompt:

`%comspec% /?`

Comment: Thank you! I managed to use your solution by changing the path to `"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvarsall.bat"` specifically for mine to work. Appreciate the educational notes as well.