# Building a win32 app with CMake, Ninja, and MSVC

Tags: windows, visual-c++, cmake, ninja

I use CMake to build win32 apps by using its [Visual Studio 16 2019 generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html) and passing the following options:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32
```

I'd like to switch the Visual Studio 16 2019 generator with Ninja to build the same win32 app.  However, CMake's Ninja generator does not offer the same high-level functionality as CMake's Visual Studio generators.

So, does anyone know how to configure Ninja to build win32 apps with the MSVC compiler?

Comment: You could use Ninja generator with MSVC compiler (`cl.exe`). Just pass proper variables `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to `cmake`. If you want specific setup of `cl.exe` compiler, then see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262342/cmake-g-ninja-on-windows-specify-x64).