# How to setup visual studio developer command prompt on GitHub Actions?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmake, github-actions

In order to use CMake + Ninja + MSVC (The Visual Studio Compiler) you need to startup a [developer command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66467752/19739129).

Which under the hood is really calling `vcvarsall.bat` which is found in a visual studio installation.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat`

How can I do this via GitHub actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we use https://github.com/ilammy/msvc-dev-cmd to setup the developer command prompt for our C++ projects. It works quite well and has a nice interface.

I'm not sure if this is the most idiomatic solution but it has been working quite nicely so far.